# Is it safe to remove the modules folder from ios frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode6, llvm-clang, ios-frameworks

For a iOS Static Framework project, the output target is a .framework bundle folder with a couple subfolders, one of which is named 'Modules'. I believe this relates to XCode's new support for CLANG/LLVM modules. Is it safe to delete that folder without runtime implications? App projects that reference the framework seem to build ok with the Modules folder there or not.